# behavioral change during multicasting

Tags: java

Following is a simple statement

```
System.out.println((int)(char)(byte)-1);
```

1. when I run it I get output as `65535`. I dont know the reason for
   it.
2. During execution (byte)-1 return -1,hence `(int)(char)(byte)-1` is equivalent to `(int)(char)-1`. when I print (char)-1 it prints `?` **only** in some system but not in all systems.
3. if I ignore the 2nd point above mentioned and print (int)'?' then it
   prints 63

So my question is if I do multicast all together that is `(int)(char)(byte)-1` then I get `65535` but if I do casting part by part that

- (byte)-1
- (char)-1
- (int)'?'

then I get 63,why is it so?

Comment: `65535` is 2^16 - 1 and thatfore the highest value a `char` can have... i assume that `char` is a unsigned integer type with 2 bytes

Comment: @Exhauzt as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/11689598/2664200 max of char is 65535

Comment: It's because of the char negative value. More info -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176079/negative-char-value-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1):

First, you have an integer (32 bits) the binary representation of `-1` is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

then, it is converted to a byte (8 bits):

```
1111 1111
```

If you print that, you'll get -1 (that's the `byte` representation for -1) then, it is cast to a `char` (a 16 bit unsigned character) which will give you:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111
```

(because it will "expand" the sign) if you try to print this as a char, you'll get an "irrecognizable" character (in some systems it will print the question mark) then, you do a cast to `int`; but, a `char` is unsigned, so there is expansion os the sign (because there is no sign), so you finally have:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

which, in decimal equals 65535

For 2):

No, `(int)(char)(byte)-1` is not equivalent to `(int)(char)-1` (see explanation for #1)

Answer (score 0):

It's about converting a signed type to an unsigned one. In Java the `char` range is `[0,2^16)`. So when you try to convert `-1` (signed type, negative value) to an unsigned type you end up with

```
2^16 - 1 = 65535
```