# How to properly write evaluatePostfix function?

Tags: java, postfix-notation, incompatibletypeerror

I'm new to coding. Trying to write an evaluatePostfix function in Java. 
I keep getting an error:

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Character
>                                   stack.push(eval(token, a, b));

This is for a school assignment converting infix notation to postfix.

Following is my code block:

```
private static int evalPostfix(String postfix){
            char token = ' ';
    int a;
    int b;
    Queue<Character> postfixQ = new Queue<>();
    for (char i : postfix.toCharArray()) {
        postfixQ.enqueue(i);
    }
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    while (!postfixQ.isEmpty()){
        token = postfixQ.dequeue();
        if (isOperand(token)){
            stack.push(token);
        }
        else {
            a = stack.pop();
            b = stack.pop();
            stack.push(eval(token, a, b));
        }
    }
    if(!stack.isEmpty()){
        return stack.pop();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid postfix expression");
    }
}
```

function takes in postfix expression and evaluates the result.

this is my eval function:

```
private static int eval(char op, int a, int b){
    int result = -1;
    if (op == '+'){
        return a + b;
    }
    else if (op == '-'){
        return a - b;
    }
    else if (op == '*'){
        return a * b;
    }
    else if (op == '/'){
        return a / b;
    }
    else if (op == '^')
        return (int)Math.pow(a, b);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you provide what parameter accepting by eval fuction. As you have defined all variable - token, a, b  as char. and I think you are trying to manipulate(doing calculation) on char value in your eval method.

Comment: where are you getting the exception? is it in eval function? you can share your stacktrace as well

Comment: @Assya Kalykova pass int value instead of char in eval function for value a and b

Comment: @Assiya which `Queue` class are you using?

Comment: yes, I use Queue class, stack class

Comment: @AssiyaKalykova but is this a custom implementation, or one from some library? (it is not `java.util.Queue`) I'm just trying to compile your example...

Comment: Your     a and    b are defined as char, but in the eval function it takes     a and     b as int, changing int to char or convert     a and     b to int before passing should be able to work

Comment: so when i  dequeue postfix, how can i correctly take the value of the character (eg. if char is '0', i dont want it to be assigned as the ASCI for '0', which is 48).

Comment: changin a an b stil doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method `eval` returns an `int`, and you try to push the result onto a `Stack<Character>`.

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do here, but that does not compile, because `int` cannot be directly converted to `Character`.

You can resolve the compilation problem by inserting an explicit cast to `char`

```
stack.push((char)eval(token, a, b));
```

but that will convert the result of `eval` to a value in the range of `char`, which is problably not what you want to do for values that can easily be outside of the [[0..65535] range of `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689549/range-of-char-in-java).